# Joining two dataframes in Spark is blowing up

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, join

I am trying to join two dataframes on a single field. In order to do this, I must first make sure the field is unique. So my order of events goes:

1. Read in the first dataframe
2. Select the field I want to join on (say, `field1`), and another field I want to bring in on the join (`field2`)
3. Do `.distinct`

Then, for the second table..

1. Read in the second dataframe
2. Do a leftouter join on `field1` with the first table
3. Do `.distinct`

I have tried to run my script and it is taking way longer than it should. 
To debug this, I put a `println` for the record count on the first table before and after the join, and here were the results:

Before the join, the record count was `904,326`. After, `2,658,632`. 
So I think it is blowing up, but am not sure why. I think it has to do with trying to use only one "distinct" after selecting two fields..?

Please help!

Here is the code:

```
    val ticketProduct = Source.fromArg(args, "f1").read
   .select($"INSTRUMENT_SK", $"TICKET_CODES_SK")
   .distinct

  val instrumentD = Source.fromArg(args, "f2").read
//    println("instrumentD count before join is " + instrumentD.count)
   .join(ticketProduct, Seq("INSTRUMENT_SK"), "leftouter")
//   .select($"SERIAL_NBR", $"TICKET_CODES_SK")
   .distinct        
    println("instrumentD count after join is " + instrumentD.count)
```

Comment: Could we see the code and, if possible, the dataset?

Comment: Also, try doing distinct on each dataframe that will be joined before joining them

Comment: Here is the body of my code:

Comment: val ticketProduct = Source.fromArg(args, "f1").read
   .select($"INSTRUMENT_SK", $"TICKET_CODES_SK")
   .distinct

  val instrumentD = Source.fromArg(args, "f2").read
//    println("instrumentD count before join is " + instrumentD.count)
   
   .join(ticketProduct, Seq("INSTRUMENT_SK"), "leftouter")
//   .select($"SERIAL_NBR", $"TICKET_CODES_SK")
   .distinct        
    println("instrumentD count after join is " + instrumentD.count)
 
 //   .writeToSource(Source.fromArg(args, "output"))
    }   
  }
}

Comment: Please update your question when adding more information (code, etc)

Comment: Also, is there a better way to add code so it is more readable?

Comment: read the following entry please https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that by calling distinct you only remove rows where the values of `field1` **and** `field2` are the same.
Since you join on `field1`, you might want the values of `field1` to be unique.

You could try something like the following instead of calling `distinct`.

```
dataframe1.groupBy($"field1").agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array($"field2"))
```

This will result in a dataframe where the column `field1` is unique, and multiple values of `field2` are aggregate into an array.

The same applies to the second dataframe.

To give an example: Say you have dataframes with the following content.

```
field1, field2
 1,       1
 1,       2

field1, field3
 1,      1
 1,      3
```

Then distinct does nothing to them, since the rows are distinct.
Now if you would do a join on `field1` you would get the following.

```
 1, 1, 1
 1, 2, 1
 1, 1, 3
 1, 2, 3
```

The aggregation in contrast would give

```
field1, array_of_field2
 1,      [1,2]

field1, array_of field3
 1,      [1,3]
```

Then a  join would then result in the following dataframe.

```
1, [1,2], [1,3]
```

Comment: Eventually, I will want the values of the field2, or ticket_codes_sk, to be distinct as well because I am going to perform another join using that. So should I use the same approach with this field as well?

Comment: Yes with the second you would have to do the same.

Comment: Ok ok ok.. I think I still don't understand completely. Was your solution going to look at the two fields together, taking the unique values of field1 and grouping the corresponding values from field2 into an array? Therefore when I get to using the value from field2 in my next join, it would have these values that resulted from the agg? I don't think this is what I want... I just want to make the values for each field from the first table are unique so that the two joins later on don't blow up..

Comment: In other words, I don't want to look at the two fields together when I grab the unique values, but rather make them both distinct separately..

Comment: It was also suggested that perhaps instead of a join, I may want to consider a union and taking only the first row of one of the dataframes? I'm not sure what was meant by this..

Comment: I added an example to the answer. Hope that clarifies the idea.